# Text beside table row in HTML

Tags: html, html-table

I'm kind of new to front-end development and I have this problem: I want to show text beside each row of the table (on the left) and upon every column. The result would be similar to a chessboard:

[image]

How can I manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a HTML table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="outside"></td>
    <td class="outside">1</td>
    <td class="outside">2</td>
    <td class="outside">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="outside">A</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="outside">B</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="outside">C</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And add CSS styling:

```
.outside {border:none;}
table {border-collapse: collapse; height: 250px; width: 250px;}
th, td {border: 1px solid black;}
td {text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;}
```

However, looking at bootstrap's grid layout would be a better alternative.
www.getbootstrap.com

Here is a working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/JWP5RvA5sOATseliVveg?p=preview

Comment: This is exactly how I would do it (If I didn't use bootstrap)

Answer (score 1):

This is not perfect but is a mock of what it could look like.

What I have did is made a 3x3 Grid, where the top and left of the grid contains the numbers and the inside contains the border display.

HTML

```
<div id="grid">
  <div class="grid-element outside"></div>
  <div class="grid-element outside">
    <span class="top-content">1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-element outside">
    <span class="top-content">2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-element outside">
    <span class="left-content">A<span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-element"></div>
  <div class="grid-element"></div>
  <div class="grid-element outside">
    <span class="left-content">B<span>
   </div>
  <div class="grid-element"></div>
  <div class="grid-element"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .clear {
  clear: both;
}

#grid {
  width: 610px;
}

.grid-element {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  border:1px solid #000;
}

.outside{
  border:1px solid #fff;
   position: relative;
}

.top-content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right:50%;
}

.left-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right:10px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zfv7d2ro/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I should try to nest two tables.

You can try something like this:

**HTML**

```
<table class="outer" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="3" id="inner-container">
                <div class="inner">
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer th {
    padding: 5px 20px;
}


.outer > tbody > tr > td {
    padding: 20px 5px;
}

.outer th,
.outer td {
    text-align: center;
}

.inner {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.inner table {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.inner td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

#inner-container {
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

Here's my demo: https://jsfiddle.net/dnxgcoyo/1/